# 750 GeV diphoton resonance: KK graviton?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, string-theory, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model

As everybody of you may know at LHC they found this *probable* resonance (https://cds.cern.ch/record/2114808, https://cds.cern.ch/record/2114853?ln=en). It may be a scalar or a KK graviton mode. Now, checking arxiv, one can basically find a lot of models inherent scalars and pseudoscalars trying to explain this resonance.

I am asking: *theoretically* supposing this resonance is true, can it really be a KK graviton mode? In which model can it produce a diphoton? By coupling to what?

(It's a purely *speculative* question, but still I would like to understand if anyone has thought to KK graviton models.)

Comment: Wouldn't that only occur at this energy scale if we also had compact extra-dimensions that would show themselves in non-Newtonian gravity at the sub-mm level? I thought that train has left the station with all non-Newtonian gravity experiments failing to see anything?

Comment: so far, no resonance has been found. We are still around the 3 sigmas statistical fluctuation. There were many discoveries in the history of particle physics of this kind which turned out to be background fluctuations later on. So prudence before drawing premature conclusions...

Comment: @Paganini: Even a high energy physicist can occasionally dream... I have been watching the long faces at the presentations of CERN data for years now... 30 years of work to build it and run it and nothing but a standard Higgs? That would be a meager result, indeed. You are right, though. Unfortunately.

Comment: @CuriousOne: sure, as many physicists, I also hope/dream that this bump is the real first sign of something beyond the Standard Model!

Comment: Ok, edited. Now answer please, if u have understood this point.

Comment: Around three sigma is when you hear people start noodling things in the hallways, but that is always done in the knowledge that you're still in early days. Around four sigma they'll start drafting papers in large numbers, but many will hold off on even submitting to arXiv until there is motion toward five sigma.